# Placeholder drawable not updated when running an activity in productive environment

Tags: android, textview, imageview, drawable

I had an XML layout containing a placeholder **image**, which was meant to be replaced dynamically by **other** ones as usage of application progressed. The image was set as a drawable next to `TextView` component (`android:drawableLeft` and `android:drawableStart`) and was switched dynamically using `textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(selectedImageId, 0, 0, 0);` method.

Everything worked fine in emulated environment, but unfortunately, didn't work in productive: on real devices the placeholder image was displayed instead of the one to be set dynamically. All images following the first one (the placeholder) were displayed correctly, though. Changing the order of methods (to make the image setter executed at the end) didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to define an `ImageView` component left to the `TextView` and set image using `theImage.setImageResource(selectedImageId);`.